# Can Big-O and Big-theta be used interchangibly?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, notation

I am studying the book Introduction to Algorithms, by Thomas H. Corman. I am studying the asymptotic notation. One thing is bothering me, because the author stated that:

f(n)=Big-theta(g(n)) implies f(n)=Big-O(g(n)) , **since Big-theta notation is stronger notion than O-notation.**
 **HOW??**

and the author also stated that *(an^2+bn+c)*, where a>0, is in *Big-theta(n^2)* also shows that such quadratic function is in *Big-O(n^2)*. **HOW??**

Comment: This is a duplicate of a number of other questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230122/big-oh-vs-big-theta
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-n-and-on

Comment: @ulmangt; the couple of the same links I searched ,didn't find any answer that could have clear my confusion. that's why I asked it SO.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused a bit with the terms.

`f(n) = O(g(n))` - means that `g(n)` is an upper bound of `f(n)`. Formally - exist const `n0, c`, such that for all `n>n0, f(n)<= c*g(n)`. You can imagine it as two graphs, such that `c*g(n)` is upper than `f(n)`.
For example : `5n^2+n = O(n^2)`

Why ?

Because if, for example, `n0=10` and `c=10`, then for all `n>n0` - `5n^2+n <= 10*n^2`

`f(n) = Theta(g(n))` - means that `g(n)` is an upper and a lower bound of `f(n)`. Formally - exist const `n0, c1, c2`, such that for all `n>n0, c1*g(n)<=f(n)<=c2*g(n)`. You can imagine it as three graphs, such that `f(n)` is between `c1*g(n)` and `c2*g(n)`. 
For example : `5n^2+n = Theta(n^2)`

Why ?

Because if, for example, `n0=100` and `c1=1,c2=100` then for all `n>n0` - `n^2<=5n^2+n<=100*n^2`

Answer (score 0):

(In V1 of the book) the definition of f() being in Theta(g(n)) is that there are positive constants C1 and C2 such that 0 <= C1g(n) <= f(n) <= C2g(n) for all n >= N0

The definition of O(g(n)) is that there is a single C such that 0 <= f(n) <= Cg(n) for all n >= N0

So if you can find big enough constants N0, C1 and C2 to satisfy the first definition, you can use constants N0 and C = C2 to satisfy the second definition. Therefore the first definition is stronger than the second in the sense that anything that satisfies the first satisfies the second - and the business about the quadratic is a special case of this.