# Does every algorithm have Big Omega?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Does every algorithm have  Big Omega?

Is it possible for algorithms to have both Big O and Big Omega (but not equal to each other- not Big Theta) ?

For instance Quicksort's Big O  - O(n log n) But does it have Big Omega? If it does, how do i calculate it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure quick-sort is O(n^2).

Comment: Any algorithm can be said to be `Omega(1)` :)

Comment: @Dukeling I think the right way to say this is that quicksort is O(n log n) in the average case and O(n^2) in the worst case. See my answer for a discussion of the distinction between case and bound, which I think is pertinent to this question.

Answer (score 9):

First, it is of paramount importance that one not confuse the *bound* with the *case*. A *bound* - like Big-Oh, Big-Omega, Big-Theta, etc. - says something about a rate of growth. A *case* says something about the kinds of input you're currently considering being processed by your algorithm.

Let's consider a very simple example to illustrate the distinction above. Consider the canonical "linear search" algorithm:

```
LinearSearch(list[1...n], target)
1. for i := 1 to n do
2.    if list[i] = target then return i
3. return -1
```

There are three broad kinds of cases one might consider: best, worst, and average cases for inputs of size `n`. In the best case, what you're looking for is the first element in the list (really, within any fixed number of the start of the list). In such cases, it will take no more than some constant amount of time to find the element and return from the function. Therefore, the Big-Oh and Big-Omega happen to be the same for the best case: `O(1)` and `Omega(1)`. When both `O` and `Omega` apply, we also say `Theta`, so this is `Theta(1)` as well.

In the worst case, the element is not in the list, and the algorithm must go through all `n` entries. Since `f(n) = n` happens to be a function that is bound from above and from below by the same class of functions (linear ones), this is `Theta(n)`.

Average case analysis is usually a bit trickier. We need to define a probability space for viable inputs of length `n`. One might say that all valid inputs (where integers can be represented using 32 bits in unsigned mode, for instance) are equally probable. From that, one could work out the average performance of the algorithm as follows:

1. Find the probability that `target` is not represented in the list. Multiply by `n`.
2. Given that `target` is in the list at least once, find the probability that it appears at position `k` for each `1 <= k <= n`. Multiply each `P(k)` by `k`.
3. Add up all of the above to get a function in terms of `n`.

Notice that in step 1 above, if the probability is non-zero, we will definitely get at least a linear function (exercise: we can never get more than a linear function). However, if the probability in step 1 is indeed zero, then the assignment of probabilities in step 2 makes all the difference in determining the complexity: you can have best-case behavior for some assignments, worst-case for others, and possibly end up with behavior that isn't the same as best (constant) or worst (linear).

Sometimes, we might speak loosely of a "general" or "universal" case, which considers all kinds of input (not just the best or the worst), but that doesn't give any particular weighting to inputs and doesn't take averages. In other words, you consider the performance of the algorithm in terms of an upper-bound on the worst-case, and a lower-bound on the best-case. This seems to be what you're doing.

Phew. Now, back to your question.

Are there functions which have different `O` and `Omega` bounds? Definitely. Consider the following function:

```
f(n) = 1 if n is odd, n if n is even.
```

The best case is "`n` is odd", in which case `f` is `Theta(1)`; the worst case is "`n` is even", in which case `f` is `Theta(n)`; and if we assume for the average case that we're talking about 32-bit unsigned integers, then `f` is `Theta(n)` in the average case, as well. However, if we talk about the "universal" case, then `f` is `O(n)` and `Omega(1)`, and not `Theta` of anything. An algorithm whose runtime behaves according to `f` might be the following:

```
Strange(list[1...n], target)
1. if n is odd then return target
2. else return LinearSearch(list, target)
```

Now, a more interesting question might be whether there are algorithms for which some case (besides the "universal" case) cannot be assigned some valid `Theta` bound. This is interesting, but not overly so. The reason is that you, during your analysis, are allowed to choose the cases that constitutes best- and worst-case behavior. If your first choice for the case turns out not to have a `Theta` bound, you can simply exclude the inputs that are "abnormal" for your purposes. The case and the bound aren't completely independent, in that sense: you can often choose a case such that it has "good" bounds.

*But can you always do it?*

I don't know, but that's an interesting question.

Answer (score 8):

### Does every algorithm have a Big Omega?

Yes. Big Omega is a **lower bound**. Any algorithm can be said to take **at least** constant time, so any algorithm is `Ω(1)`.

### Does every algorithm have a Big O?

No. Big O is a **upper bound**. Algorithms that don't (reliably) terminate don't have a Big O.

An algorithm has an upper bound if we can say that, in the absolute worst case, the algorithm will not take longer than this. I'm pretty sure `O(∞)` is not valid notation.

### When will the Big O and Big Omega of an algorithm be equal?

**There is actually a special notation for when they *can* be equal:** [Big Theta (Θ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376740/what-exactly-does-big-%D3%A8-notation-represent).

They will be equal if the algorithm scales perfectly with the size of the input (meaning there aren't input sizes where the algorithm is suddenly a lot more efficient).

This is assuming we take Big O to be the smallest possible upper bound and Big Omega to be the largest possible lower bound. This is not actually required from the definition, but they're commonly informally treated as such. If you drop this assumption, you can find a Big O and Big Omega that aren't equal for *any* algorithm.

**Brute force prime number checking** (where we just loop through all smaller numbers and try to divide them into the target number) is perhaps a good example of when the smallest upper bound and largest lower bound are not equal.

Assume you have some number `n`. Let's also for the time being ignore the fact that bigger numbers take longer to divide (a similar argument holds when we take this into account, although the actual complexities would be different). And I'm also calculating the complexity based on the number itself instead of the *size* of the number (which can be the number of bits, and could change the analysis here quite a bit).

If `n` is divisible by 2 (or some other small prime), we can very quickly check whether it's prime with 1 division (or a constant number of divisions). So the largest lower bound would be `Ω(1)`.

Now if `n` is prime, we'll need to try to divide `n` by each of the numbers up to `sqrt(n)` (I'll leave the reason we don't need to go higher than this as an exercise). This would take `O(sqrt(n))`, which would also then be our smallest upper bound.

So the algorithm would be `Ω(1)` and `O(sqrt(n))`.

**Exact complexity also may be hard to calculate** for some particularly complex algorithms. In such cases it may be much easier and acceptable to simply calculate some reasonably close lower and upper bounds and leave it at that. I don't however have an example on hand for this.

### How does this relate to best case and worst case?

Do not confuse upper and lower bounds for best and worst case. This is a common mistake, and a bit confusing, but [they're not the same](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/how-do-o-and-%CE%A9-relate-to-worst-and-best-case). This is a whole other topic, but as a brief explanation:

The best and worst (and average) cases can be calculated for every single input size. The upper and lower bounds can then be used for each of those 3 cases (separately). You can think of each of those cases as a line on a graph with input size on the x-axis and time on the y-axis and then, for each of those lines, the upper and lower bounds are lines which need to be strictly above or below that line as the input size tends to infinity (this isn't 100% accurate, but it's a good basic idea).

**Quick-sort** has a worst-case of `Θ(n2)` (when we pick the worst possible pivot at every step) and a best-case of `Θ(n log n)` (when we pick good pivots). Note the use of Big Theta, meaning each of those are both lower and upper bounds.

Let's compare quick-sort with the above prime checking algorithm:

- Say you have a given number `n`, and `n` is 53. Since it's prime, it will (always) take around `sqrt(53)` steps to determine whether it's prime. So the best and worst cases are all the same.
- Say you want to sort some array of size `n`, and `n` is 53. Now those 53 elements can be arranged such that quick-sort ends up picking really bad pivots and run in around `532` steps (the worst case) or really good pivots and run in around `53 log 53` steps (the best case). So the best and worst cases are different.
- Now take `n` as 54 for each of the above:

  - For prime checking, it will only take around `1` step to determine that 54 is prime. The best and worst cases are the same again, but they're different from what they were for 53.
  - For quick-sort, you'll again have a worst case of around `542` steps and a best case of around `54 log 54` steps.

So for quick-sort the worst case always takes around `n2` steps and the best case always takes around `n log n` steps. So the lower and upper (or "tight") bound of the worst case is `Θ(n2)` and the tight bound of the best case is `Θ(n log n)`.

For our prime checking, sometimes the worst case takes around `sqrt(n)` steps and sometimes it takes around `1` step. So the lower bound for the worse case would be `Ω(1)` and upper bound would be `O(sqrt(n))`. It would be the same for the best case.

Note that above I simply said "the algorithm would be `Ω(1)` and `O(sqrt(n))`". This is slightly ambiguous, as it's not clear whether the algorithm always takes the same amount of time for some input size, or the statement is referring to one of the best, average or worst case.

### How do I calculate this?

It's hard to give general advice for this since proofs of bounds are greatly dependent on the algorithm. You'd need to analyse the algorithm similar to what I did above to figure out the worst and best cases.

Answer (score 1):

Big O and Big Omega it can be calculated for every algorithm as you can see in [Big-oh vs big-theta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230122/big-oh-vs-big-theta)

Comment: Would've been better suited as a comment.