# Why is theta notation never used?

Tags: big-o

I'm studying a degree in computer science and at class we're using big-theta notation much more often than big-O notation. Although while reading articles about algorithms and its running times, I hardly ever find the big-theta notation anywhere. Why isn't theta notation used to indicate worst case of running time for algorithms in a more fitted way in most books and articles?

Comment: We were taught only about Big-O notation in college days..Honestly I never heard about both Big-Theta and Big-Omega until I started exploring DS and algorithms again in my professional career.  Even though if they are not in use but it is indeed important to know that something like that exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Big-O is an upper bound.
- Big-Theta is a tight bound, i.e. upper and lower bound.

When people only worry about what's the worst that can happen, big-O is sufficient; i.e. it says that "it can't get much worse than this". The tighter the bound the better, of course, but a tight bound isn't always easy to compute [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3230152/2589776).

---

The following opinion [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3230535/2589776) will give you a better understanding:

As people said, big-Theta is a two-sided bound. Strictly speaking, you should use it when you want to explain that that is how well an algorithm can do, and that either that algorithm can't do better or that no algorithm can do better. For instance, if you say "Sorting requires Θ(n(log n)) comparisons for worst-case input", then you're explaining that there is a sorting algorithm that uses O(n(log n)) comparisons for any input; and that for every sorting algorithm, there is an input that forces it to make Ω(n(log n)) comparisons.

Now, one narrow reason that people use O instead of Ω is to drop disclaimers about worst or average cases. If you say "sorting requires O(n(log n)) comparisons", then the statement still holds true for favorable input. Another narrow reason is that even if one algorithm to do X takes time Θ(f(n)), another algorithm might do better, so you can only say that the complexity of X itself is O(f(n)).

However, there is a broader reason that people informally use O. At a human level, it's a pain to always make two-sided statements when the converse side is "obvious" from context. Since I'm a mathematician, I would ideally always be careful to say "I will take an umbrella if and only if it rains" or "I can juggle 4 balls but not 5", instead of "I will take an umbrella if it rains" or "I can juggle 4 balls". But the other halves of such statements are often obviously intended or obviously not intended. It's just human nature to be sloppy about the obvious. It's confusing to split hairs.

Unfortunately, in a rigorous area such as math or theory of algorithms, it's also confusing not to split hairs. People will inevitably say O when they should have said Ω or Θ. Skipping details because they're "obvious" always leads to misunderstandings. There is no solution for that.