# Time complexity of nested loop, whether it's Big O or Big Theta?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
   for (int j=1; j<i; j++)
       for (int k=j; k<n; k++)
           cout << "Hello world" << endl;
```

I know the time complexity is obtained by looking at how many times this iterates to produce `Hello world`. I am confused on whether time complexity is O(n<sup>3</sup>) or Θ(n<sup>3</sup>)?

Comment: Do you know what the difference is? The code btw. is both.

Comment: How is it both? Could you please help me understand in clear way?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3230152/5414176) answer for some detail.

Answer (score 1):

Big O notation indicicates the "worst case". Here you have no worst case, you loop a specific amount of times. Theta means upper and lower bound, and since those two are equal in your scenario, it is Theta.

Comment: To clarify, it is also O(n^3), but Theta is more precise.

Comment: Thanks. Ya, I understand if it's big Theta then, it's also Big O. But, what is the condition that it can only be in Big Theta or Big omega? How do we identify it exactly? Is there any links to explain this?

Comment: @ashish The complexity of your code is also in O(n^4) but not in Theta(n^4). Since Theta(f(n)) always implies O(f(n)) the other case is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's both.
Big O gives you the upper bound of runtime while Big Theta gives you both upper and lower bound.
If a function is represented in Big Theta then it includes both Big O and Big Omega.
Mathematically,

```
if f(n)=O(g(n)) then 0<=f(n)<=Cg(n) for any positive constant C.

if f(n)=Theta(g(n)) then c1g(n)<=f(n)<=c2g(n) for any positive constants c1 and c2.
```

In your problem the runtime is a third degree polynomial in n, a polynomial function can be represented in Big theta with it's highest power in n.

So it is both `Big O(n^3)` and `Big Theta(n^3)` and also `Big Omega(n^3)`.