# Algorithms and determining theta(b)

Tags: algorithm

Given an equation i have to determine theta(b) and i am struggling to do so:

For example:

Question:
Determine for term 1 the term 2 such that we have a = Theta(b).

1) 3n+5n^2+7

2)

A. n^2

B. n^3

C. log(n)

D. root(n)

E. 3^n

F. 2^n

G. n

H. 1

I. n^1.5

In other words i need to match the term from 1) with a term from 2)

Can someone please guide me on how to do this?

I have tried using a calculator but I don't think this is correct as i am not sure how you would do theta(b)

Comment: i dont understand @sinanspd

Comment: Theta is a special function in mathematics that describes the limiting behavior of a function similar to Big O. You can read about the differences here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230122/big-oh-vs-big-theta

Here the question asks you to pair functions f & g such that f is bounded both above and below by g asymptotically.

You can read about theta here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376740/what-exactly-does-big-%D3%A8-notation-represent

Do a some digging on Big Theta & what it means. A lot of resources online. Once you understand it, the answer should be straightforward